# How to write ajax function to show pop-up window for user already registered?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, dropwizard

I am working on dropwizard-java project.When users click subscribe button, it shows thanks for subscribe and then check for validation, whether already registered or not.

I need to display,once clicked immediately show pop-up window as registerd or not.I am very new to work in ajax.If anyone knows solution,please help to solve.

```
    <form action="/subscribe" method="post" id="forms" >   
            <p> 
              <span>
                <input name="sent_email" id="mailid"  type="text" required pattern="[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
              </span>
            </p>
          </form>


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        @POST
        @Path("subscribe")
        public boolean sentEmail(@FormParam("sent_email") String input) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
                ParseException, java.text.ParseException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {

        //Reading json file and checking whether it contains input
        if(condition)
        {
            //Code
                    return "Already registered";
                } else {
           //write into file
        }
            return null;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:-

Return true/false on basis of user existence with system.
Check the ajax response, if it is true (i.e. user exits) then show popup.

```
$.ajax({
url : 'https://www.lennu.net/',
}).done(function(data) {
if (data == true) {
    alert("User already registered.")
}
}).fail(function() {
alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
})
```